# Server responds with a non-JavaScript MIME type of ""

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, mime

I want to wrap an angular application with cordova. 
After hitting `"cordova run android"` and inspecting it in Chrome, the console states:

> "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced
>   for module scripts per HTML spec."

On my phone I obviously only get a white screen then. How can I solve this issue?

When i hit `"cordova serve"` and look at it in the browser on my PC, there are no errors thrown and everything works fine.

Thank you in advance.

[MIME type of ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVdGr.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could figure it out, even if it is not a great solution I guess and there might be something nicer.

After running `ng build --prod --aot` I went into my index.html and put
`type="text/javascript"` into the `<script>` tags.

So basically from

`<script src="runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module">`

to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module">`

After that I got no more errors.

Comment: 5 hours wasted... Thank you!

Comment: only 5 hours wasted? 
You're lucky

Comment: @SebastianWeiß can you help me please, im having the same issue